# Problem Extending Django-Oscar's layout.html

Tags: django, django-oscar

The problem appeared after I added a template to a minimal webapp. The template `extends` django-oscar's `layout.html`. Nothing else in the project `extends` `layout.html`.

My goal is simply to be able to use django-oscar templates to form the basis of web pages in my webapp. For some reason I am having no end of issues. This is only the latest error message. I have been struggling with this for days! When I resolve one issue, another shows up.

I made a minimal git repo for this problem: https://github.com/mslinn/django_oscar_problem
The repo has a `requirements.txt` file in case anyone wants to install the PIP modules necessary run the program.

I tried to ensure that I had the simplest possible project that shows the problem. In `README.md` I show the complete error message displayed in the web browser.

```
# /templates/welcome.html

{% extends 'oscar/layout.html' %}
... etc ...
```

```py
# main/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, 'home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, 'admin'),
    path('hello/', views.hello, 'hello'),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

```py
# main/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "welcome.html", {})
```

I then ran the webapp with:

```sh
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

The error message in the web browser after visiting [http://localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000/) is:

```
ValueError at /

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     3.1.6
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, 'home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, 'admin'),
    path('hello/', views.hello, 'hello'),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

The arguments you're passing to `path()` are not quite right. The [signature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) for path is:

```
path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)
```

i.e., the third positional argument is expected to be `kwargs` passed to the view function - but you've passed a string instead, which is what causes the somewhat obscure error. I think you intend this to be the `name`, in which case you need to supply that as a named argument, i.e.,:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello'),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

Note that this then results in a new `TemplateDoesNotExist` error in your sample repo - this is because the location of the `templates` directory is not somewhere that Django knows to look. You can fix this by adding the path to that directory to the [DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS) configuration in your template settings, which is currently set to `[]`.

Comment: Wow, can't wait to try this tomorrow. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Just looking at the code lol. If you spend as much time working with Django as I do you tend to develop a sense of where to look for issues.

Comment: Seems like `re_path` (and `path`) do not follow the convention described in the [Ordering Arguments](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3#ordering-arguments) section of **How To Use *args and **kwargs in Python 3**